# Kotlin Map Type Inference Failed

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, compiler-errors

I created a map from two lists of mutable strings in Kotlin using:

```
val mapNames = mutableMapOf(Pair(initList, nameList))
```

When I try to access the values of one of the keys I have tried

`print(mapNames.get("BB")) and print(mapNames["BB"])` and it throws the error

> error: type inference failed. The value of the type parameter K should
> be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected
> type). Try to specify it explicitly.

Both lists are lists of strings and I am just trying to simply return the value associated with the key. I have tried to explicitly specify its type as String and am still thrown an error. I am wondering what I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not created a `Map<String, String>`. You have created a `Map<List<String>, List<String>>`. The only key in the map is `initList`, and it corresponds to the value `nameList`. That's obviously not what you want. You want each thing in `initList` to match up with each thing in `nameList` and form an entry in the map, so that you get a `Map<String, String>`, right?

To do this, you should `zip` the lists:

```
val mapNames = initList.zip(nameList).toMap(mutableMapOf())
```

[`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) here creates a `List<Pair<String, String>>`, and `mutableMapOf` will turn each pair in that list into a map entry. Then you can access the map as expected.

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted I realize now my error! However when doing it this way I am now getting an error saying "Type mismatch: inferred type is List<Pair<String, String>> but Pair<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)> was expected".

Comment: @IsaiahStapleton Ah, my bad. I forgot that `mutableMapOf` only takes varargs. Once you have a `List<Pair<String, String>>`, `toMap` is available, so you can just use that instead.

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much I appreciate it :)